# After unlock an Android device, how to access it via `adb shell` with `root` permission

Tags: android, adb

I unlocked my Nexus 7 device, and it shows

`lock state : unlocked`

However, when I used `adb shell` to connect it, I still couldn't `ls /data`, and got the error `opendir failed, Permission denied`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a while and found the reason:

I tried `sudo ls /data`, it didn't work.

while a way that works is like:

`su`         // after this, you get the root permission

`ls /data`